# CUDA compilation inOpenCV in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, cuda, opencv

I'm trying to compile programs in OpenCV 3.2.0 with CUDA, I have a Graphic Card Nvidia Gforce 950M (Maxwell) and I use Arch Linux

First of all, I had installed on Arch Linux X64 and  the lastest versions of nvidia, nvidia-settings, gcc-5 and cuda

On Cmake I choose gcc-5 for compilation and it's my Cmake Compilation file for CUDA

```
BUILD_CUDA_STUBS=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudaarithm=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudabgsegm=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudafeatures2d=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudafilters=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudaimgproc=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudalegacy=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudaobjdetect=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudaoptflow=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudastereo=ON
BUILD_opencv_cudawarping=ON
CUDA_ARCH_BIN = 5.0 5.2
CUDA_ARCH_PTX =
CUDA_FAST_MATH = ON
CUDA_GENERATION = Maxwell
CUDA_HOST_COMPILER = /usr/bin/gcc-5
CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION = OFF
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR = /opt/cuda
WITH_CUDA = ON
```

(Values from image of Cmake GUI)

After the Compilation of OpenCV, I load the libraries in QT Creator

```
    TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_cudaarithm -lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudacodec -lopencv_features2d  -lopencv_cudafilters -lopencv_cudaimgproc -lopencv_cudalegacy -lopencv_cudaobjdetect -lopencv_cudaoptflow -lopencv_cudastereo -lopencv_cudawarping -lopencv_videoio

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include



unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/cuda/include/
LIBS += -L /opt/cuda/include/



unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../opt/cuda/lib64/ -lcudart

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opt/cuda/lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opt/cuda/lib64
```

I try to compile the cascadeclassifier_nvidia_api.cpp but I have the following **CUDA Error**:

```
NCV Assertion Failed: No GPU found or the library is compiled without CUDA support, file = ../CUDA/main.cpp, line=163
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you run `lspci | grep -i nvidia` and verify that the card is being detected? Also AFAIK [Arch is not a supported OS for the CUDA tookit.](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#axzz4YAF1BtWc)

Comment: Thanks for respone, it's my command output  `[josejacomeb@lenovo-idepad-700 release]$ sudo lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)`, I have  tried some solutions and when I compile with g++-5, I can avoid the error